# Using a cookie to store data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in the process of creating a login and register page for an website. I decided to use a cookie to store the registered data rather than using PHP. How exactly I would do this? I have basic details like firstname, surname, birthday, username, email and password. I want to store the details so when the user registers with the site, they can then login with what they have registered with. This is all done in a form which is below:

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="getdropdownvalue()">
  <table bgcolor="white" width="700" border="0" align="center">
    <col width="200">
      <col width="200">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="grey">Fill the form to sign up.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">Fields marked with * are mandatory</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name*</td>
          <td>Surname*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" class="info" />
              <td>
                <label>
                  <input type="text" name="txtsurname" id="txtsurname" class="info" />
                </label>
              </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Create Username*</td>
          <td>Birthday</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="info" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="DOBMonth">
              <option>Month</option>
              <option value="January">January</option>
              <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
              <option value="March">March</option>
              <option value="April">April</option>
              <option value="May">May</option>
              <option value="June">June</option>
              <option value="July">July</option>
              <option value="August">August</option>
              <option value="September">September</option>
              <option value="October">October</option>
              <option value="November">November</option>
              <option value="December">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="DOBDay">
              <option>Day</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
              <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
            <select name="DOBYear">
              <option>Year</option>
              <option value="2016">2016</option>
              <option value="2015">2015</option>
              <option value="2014">2014</option>
              <option value="2013">2013</option>
              <option value="2012">2012</option>
              <option value="2011">2011</option>
              <option value="2010">2010</option>
              <option value="2009">2009</option>
              <option value="2008">2008</option>
              <option value="2007">2007</option>
              <option value="2006">2006</option>
              <option value="2005">2005</option>
              <option value="2004">2004</option>
              <option value="2003">2003</option>
              <option value="2002">2002</option>
              <option value="2001">2001</option>
              <option value="2000">2000</option>
              <option value="1999">1998</option>
              <option value="1998">1998</option>
              <option value="1997">1997</option>
              <option value="1996">1996</option>
              <option value="1995">1995</option>
              <option value="1994">1994</option>
              <option value="1993">1993</option>
              <option value="1992">1992</option>
              <option value="1991">1991</option>
              <option value="1990">1990</option>
              <option value="1989">1989</option>
              <option value="1988">1988</option>
              <option value="1987">1987</option>
              <option value="1986">1986</option>
              <option value="1985">1985</option>
              <option value="1984">1984</option>
              <option value="1983">1983</option>
              <option value="1982">1982</option>
              <option value="1981">1981</option>
              <option value="1980">1980</option>
              <option value="1979">1979</option>
              <option value="1978">1978</option>
              <option value="1977">1977</option>
              <option value="1976">1976</option>
              <option value="1975">1975</option>
              <option value="1974">1974</option>
              <option value="1973">1973</option>
              <option value="1972">1972</option>
              <option value="1971">1971</option>
              <option value="1970">1970</option>
              <option value="1969">1969</option>
              <option value="1968">1968</option>
              <option value="1967">1967</option>
              <option value="1966">1966</option>
              <option value="1965">1965</option>
              <option value="1964">1964</option>
              <option value="1963">1963</option>
              <option value="1962">1962</option>
              <option value="1961">1961</option>
              <option value="1960">1960</option>
              <option value="1959">1959</option>
              <option value="1958">1958</option>
              <option value="1957">1957</option>
              <option value="1956">1956</option>
              <option value="1955">1955</option>
              <option value="1954">1954</option>
              <option value="1953">1953</option>
              <option value="1952">1952</option>
              <option value="1951">1951</option>
              <option value="1950">1950</option>
              <option value="1949">1949</option>
              <option value="1948">1948</option>
              <option value="1947">1947</option>
            </select>
            <tr>
              <td>Email*</td>
              <td>Confirm Email*</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>
                  <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail(txtemail)" />
                  <td>
                    <label>
                      <input type="text" name="txtemail2" id="txtemail2" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail2(txtemail2)" />
                    </label>
                  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password*</td>
              <td>Confirm Pasword*</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>
                  <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="info" />
                  <td>
                    <label>
                      <input type="password" name="txtpassword2" id="txtpassword2" class="info" />
                    </label>
                  </td>
            </tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">**Passwords must be at least 8 characters in lenght.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="terms" value="terms" id="terms" />I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="notify" value="notify" id="notify" />I want to receive notifications by text/email about new products in stock.</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login" onclick="checkdetails()" />
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>
              <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sensitive information should not be stored in a cookie, it should be encrypted and stored in a database.

Comment: Yes, you should be using a database or similar. A cookie will not store user details for a long period of time which is not what you want.

Comment: it is only for an assignment though. after may it wont be used again.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to save form data within a cookie (which is not recommended as stated in the comments), you will have to use JavaScript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

function setCookie(name, value)
{
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}

function storeValues(form)  
{
    setCookie("field1", form.field1.value);// replace with your form fields
    setCookie("field2", form.field2.value);
    setCookie("field3", form.field3.value);
    setCookie("field4", form.field4.value);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Also, you will need to call the `setCookie` function by calling it when the form's submit button is clicked, like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="storeValues(this.form)" value="Submit" />
```